# Sequelize query to find all records that falls in between date range

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have a model with columns:

```
from: { type: Sequelize.DATE }
to: { type: Sequelize.DATE }
```

I want to query all records whose either `from` OR `to` falls in between the date ranges: `[startDate, endDate]`

I tried something like:

```
const where = {
    $or: [{
        from: {
            $lte: startDate,
            $gte: endDate,
        },
        to: {
            $lte: startDate,
            $gte: endDate,
        },
    }],
};
```

Something like:

```
SELECT * from MyTable WHERE (startDate <= from <= endDate) OR (startDate <= to <= endDate
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get any error? What is the SQL generated by this query?

Comment: it's because your query is wrong. `from: { $gte: startDate, $lte:endDate }`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The solution which works for me is this:

```javascript
// Here startDate and endDate are Date objects
const where = {
    from: {
        $between: [startDate, endDate]
    }
};
```

For reference to know more about operators: *[Querying, Operators](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#operators)*

**Note:**

In MySQL, the `between` comparison operator is **inclusive**, which means it is equivalent to the expression `(startDate <= from AND from <= endDate)`.

Comment: $between is boundary exclusive? Does it include if `from === startDate || from === endDate`

Comment: @ShankarRegmi `Between` comparison in MYSQL is **inclusive** . For more https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If the `from` date is *before* the start date, the `to` date could still be between start and end. If the goal is to check for an *overlapping time period*, it's necessary to check that `to` is *before* start *and* that `from` is *after* end.

Answer (score 38):

Try this condition. What I think you are asking will do so.

**For a new version of Sequelize:**

```
const where = {
    [Op.or]: [{
        from: {
            [Op.between]: [startDate, endDate]
        }
    }, {
        to: {
            [Op.between]: [startDate, endDate]
        }
    }]
};
```

**OR as your code structure:**

```
const where = {
    $or: [{
        from: {
            $between: [startDate, endDate]
        }
    }, {
        to: {
            $between: [startDate, endDate]
        }
    }]
};
```

For more information, you can follow this [Sequelize official documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html#combinations).

Comment: Why would you need both start and end date for both the from and to positions?

Comment: @CecilRodriguez Need to check if any of the date from separate two field found between those dates. And also he specifically asked for that in the question.

Answer (score 13):

**Step 1**

Require the Op from SEQUELIZE:

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize');
```

**Step 2**

Declare two constants:

```
const startedDate = new Date("2020-12-12 00:00:00");
const endDate = new Date("2020-12-26 00:00:00");
```

**Step 3**

```
table.findAll({where : {"fieldOfYourDate" : {[Op.between] : [startedDate , endDate ]}}})
.then((result) =>  res.status(200).json({data : result}))
.catch((error) =>  res.status(404).json({errorInfo: error}))
```

Comment: It's giving `Types of property '[Op.between]' are incompatible.` error, below one solves that issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/60987727/5134215
Putting here just in case anyone trying to solve same issue

Answer (score 7):

I agree with @VigneshSundaramoorthy's comment that even if `[Op.between]` works with date strings, the type definitions suggest this usage isn't officially supported. The operation wants array of **numbers**, and at least as at 28 Dec 2021, the documentation has no examples of using `Op.between` for a date range (only for number ranges).

However, we can achieve the same result in a type-compliant way, which also aligns with the Sequelize documentation:

```js
const where = {
  "date_field": {
    [Op.and]: {
      [Op.gte]: startOfDateRange,
      [Op.lte]: endOfDateRange
    }
  }
}
```

This has also has the slight advantage of being more explicit (that the search is inclusive) rather than relying on dialect behaviour for `BETWEEN`.