# TypeScript error when using Op.between in Sequelize with Dates

Tags: mysql, database, typescript, sequelize.js

I want to find all records in a MySql table which was created within a certain range of date.

So I wrote:

```js
import { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes, Op } from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  // some db connection config
  dialect: 'mysql'
})

class Patient extends Model {
  public guid!: number;
  public name!: string;

  public recordState: number = 0;
  public createdAt?: Date;
  public updatedAt?: Date
}
Patient.init({
  guid: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },

  recordState: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: 0
  },
  createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
  updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE
}, {
  sequelize,
  modelName: 'Patient',
  timestamps: false
})

Patient.findAll({
  where: {
    createdAt: {
      [Op.between]: [new Date('2020-02-02'), new Date()]
    }
  }
})
```

But, when I try to compile it with `tsc`, it reports error like:

```
sequelize.ts:50:5 - error TS2322: Type '{ [between]: Date[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | WhereAttributeHash | AndOperator | OrOperator | Literal | Where | Fn | Col | WhereOperators | Buffer | WhereGeometryOptions | (string | ... 2 more ... | Buffer)[]'.
  Types of property '[Op.between]' are incompatible.
    Type 'Date[]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | [number, number] | WhereAttributeHash | AndOperator | OrOperator | Literal | Where | ... 5 more ... | (string | ... 2 more ... | Buffer)[]'.
      Type 'Date[]' is not assignable to type '(string | number | WhereAttributeHash | Buffer)[]'.
        Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string | number | WhereAttributeHash | Buffer'.
          Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'WhereAttributeHash'.
            Index signature is missing in type 'Date'.

50     createdAt: {
       ~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

It seems I cannot use `Op.between` with a date range? But it's ok when I wrote similar code in JS.

So I wonder if there is really something wrong in my TS code or just a missing in the type definition, or maybe using `Op.between` with dates is not recommended?

Answer (score 5):

You're passing a date object instead of a string. Do this:

```
Patient.findAll({
  where: {
    createdAt: {
      [Op.between]: [new Date('2020-02-02').toISOString(), new Date().toISOString()]
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i had:

```
createdAt: {
        [Op.between]: [
          new Date(startDate).toISOString(),
          new Date(`${endDate} 23:59:59`).toISOString()
        ]
      }
```

and worked changing to:

```
createdAt: {
        [Op.and]: [
          {
            [Op.lt]: new Date(`${endDate} 23:59:59`),
            [Op.gt]: new Date(startDate)
          }
        ]
      }
```