# Sequelize select date between to columns by findAll function

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I want to make a query such as below by findAll function in Sequelize

```
select * FROM table where "2021-04-13" BETWEEN start_date_column and end_date_column
```

I tried below but getting error

```
let s = "2021-04-13";
Table.findAll(
        {where:{
            [s]: {
                [Op.between]: [sequelize.col("start_date_column"),sequelize.col("end_date_column")]
            }
        }})
```

but getting below error:

**Unknown column 'Table.2021-04-13' in 'where clause'**

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have [ANSI quotes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) enabled? That could explain why that string is being interpreted as a column.

Comment: actually ANSI_QUOTES is not enabled

Comment: If you can use the `?`-style placeholders instead of the "easy" mode `where` that'd help, along the lines of `where: [ '? BETWEEN ? AND ?', s, ... ]`. The documentation doesn't make it clear if this is even possible, though. I've never had to do this against a model, but that approach does work with "raw queries".

Comment: There is `where: sequelize.where(...)` which I think allows for considerably more flexibility.

Comment: I'm not quite comfortable with raw queries but I think I have no choice to use 2 where condition to make an artificial between query.

Comment: Well, you're comfortable enough in that you know precisely the SQL you want, so there's that...

Comment:  thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

At lease in `sequelize-typescript`, I would do this:

```
Table.findAll({
   where: {
     start_date_column: {
         [Op.lte]: today
     },
     end_date_column: {
         [Op.gte]: today
     }
   }
})
```

or this might help: [TypeScript error when using Op.between in Sequelize with Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983696/typescript-error-when-using-op-between-in-sequelize-with-dates)

Comment: Actually my first version of code was like yours but I have some doubt on using 2 query instead of between that may makes it more perform.