# Find upcoming birthday using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to find upcoming birthday for every users based on 2 scenarios,

1. In between Date1 to Date2.
2. In between Current date to "N" months.

I was trying to implement this by,

```
{
        [Op.and]: [
            Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('DATE_FORMAT', Sequelize.col('user.dob'), '%m-%d'), {
                [Op.between]: [
                    moment(dateFrom).format('MM-DD'),
                    moment(dateTo).format('MM-DD')
                ]
            }),
        ]
    }
```

But this is not returning the expected results.

FYI, The data type of DOB is,  `dob: DataTypes.DATEONLY`

Comment: what is the generated SQL query by ```sequelzie```?

Comment: If I want to select every birthday from today to next 6 months is given below

SELECT `id`, 
       `dob` 
FROM   `users` AS `user` 
WHERE  ( Date_format(`user`.`dob`, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '07-15' AND '01-15' );

Comment: the arg in left must less than the arg in the right when you are using ```BETWEEN``` but ```BETWEEN SYMMETRIC``` will works, i don't know seuelize supports.

Comment: ```2 BETWEEN 3 AND 1   -- FALSE```
```2 BETWEEN SYMMETRIC 3 AND 1   -- TRUE```

Comment: @cybercoder Yes, You are right. But If I give [Op.between]: [ 01-15, 07-15], It automatically switch the data back to large to small, when we log the sql.

WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(`user`.`dob`, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '07-15' AND '01-15');

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115151/sequelize-query-to-find-all-records-that-falls-in-between-date-range/43127894